# android : Junit send data between Activities

Tags: android, junit, android-intent

i am first time implementing Android Junit Testing so i don't know that how to pass values between two activity through intent in test cases.

so please suggest me any sites ,tutorial or demo

thanks for the help

Comment: @hanry:  Thanks.. but here is given only simple example of Junit not relating to my question

Comment: You can try this too

http://www.michaelminella.com/testing/unit-testing-with-junit-and-easymock.html

to download :JUnitClass.zip